# How to find out some particular distribution given the grouped data and a polynomial fitted to the data

Tags: distributions, fitting, polynomial

I have to analyse a set of grouped data.  The data is divided into groups by some categories for example: BP(<=60), BP((60,80]); Pulse(<75), Pulse((75,90]) & Pulse(>90) etc having many more factors affecting health.  Each of these categories have no. of people as their frequency.[Example has been given below].  I have managed to identify the distribution of some categories (for example for BP(60,80] -Normal(10.8,4.43) fits well), but some of the categories I am not able to identify and fit any statistical/Standard distributions to them (for example: BP(<=60)).  I have fitted polynomials to all the categories individually and the  R-squared value of the polynomial fitted is more than 0.95 for almost all the categories.  How can I use these polynomials to find out about the distributions of the data? Also is there any other way to find out the distributions even if I don't use these polynomials? Is there any function in R which can help me to analyse the data using these good fitted polynomials?

#### Interval[BP(<=60) Freq Relative Freq Interval BP((60,80])   Freq Relative Freq

1. 6.5                             0                   0                                                7                              0                     0
2. 8.5                               8            0.296296296                         9                               7            0.23333333
3. 10.5                             9             0.333333333                        11                         10           0.333333333
4. 12.5                             4             0.148148148                        13                          7             0.233333333
5. 14.5                             3             0.111111111                        15                          6                 0.2
6. 16.5                        3             0.111111111                        17                            0                       0
7. 18.5                        0                   0                                             Sum:                         30                 1
8. Sum:                      27                   1

Comment: It is unclear what your data really are or what exactly these polynomials are representing. What is the actual distinction between "some of the data" and the "full data" and how is that related to the grouping? What numbers is the polynomial "fitting"?  Please edit your question to make these issues clear: perhaps you could include a small example of what you are doing as an illustration.

Comment: @whuber Thanks Whuber, I have modified my question.

Comment: Thank you; your situation is much clearer now. But could you please explain what it would mean to "analyse the data"?  What are you trying to learn from them? And why are you interested in fitting distributions?